# Powershell remove installed application

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

Is it possible to remove software by the publisher name. I have tried different ways to do it but I was not able to. I can use name to remove it but some programs name doesn't match but the publisher is same.

e.g.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $PCNumber -Filter "Publisher LIKE '%$Publisher%'" | Foreach-Object { 

    Write-Host
    Write-Host "Uninstalling: $($_.Name)"
    Write-Host

    $rv = $_.Uninstall().ReturnValue 

    if($rv -eq 0)
    {
        $remove = "$drive\Program Files\software\";
        if ( (Test-Path "$remove") ){
            Remove-Item $remove -Recurse -Force
        }

        $remove = "$drive\Program Files (x86)\software\";
        if ( (Test-Path "$remove") ){
            Remove-Item $remove -Recurse -Force
        }

        Write-Host "$($_.Name) uninstalled sucessfully"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "There was an error ($rv) uninstalling $($_.Name)"
    }
}
```

I have tried this but it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$products = gwmi -class win32_product -filter "Vendor like 'Microsoft%'"
if ($products) {
    foreach ($product in $products) {
        $product
        # Processing here...
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine. Thank you for your reply.
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName "." -Filter "Vendor LIKE 'Microsoft%'" | Foreach-Object { 
        
        Write-Host
        Write-Host "Uninstalling: $($_.Name)"
        Write-Host
        
        }